# Configuring firebase project domain restrictions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database

My situation is as follows:

I have one database on Firebase. I have one app, which is on a domain. So right now I have configured the Google console like so:

[image]

But, I also have a second app which I want ***only*** to use locally, as `localhost:3000` or something similar using `npm start`. Since the app is built using React, the whole code and API keys are visible. So I need the domain restriction. Anyone who has the key and credentials can be built their own react project and just mess things up if domain like `localhost:3000` is trusted.

Changing the domain name is also not enough since attackers could just iterate through the ports and test them.

Is there any way for me to use the app locally without creating a security flaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way for your backend to identify one localhost as OK and not another.

On the other hand, if you properly configure your DB rules, attackers won't be able to add malicious-data to your production tables. And if you're looking at restricting the domain via the Google API screen, I assume you already know all about the [Firebase RTD rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: I think I may have found a workaround. I could create a new key, only for the local app, which would not be publicly available, and restrict the public key for a domain. This is far from perfect but I cannot think of anything better.

Comment: That's a good idea, it would definitely keep it secure as long as you keep that special localhost-api-key secret.